# Database design - Entity Relationship Model

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I have the following problem that I need to express.

There are persons, workplaces and sites. Each person can be assigned to multiple workplaces. Each workplace can have multiple persons. Each workplace has exactly one site. So far so good. But my problem is that each person has only one workplace at a specific site.

How can I express this in an ERM?

My idea so far:

[image: idea]

I just can't express the "one person has only one workplace at a specific site"-problem with this approach.

**Implementation Solution:**

```
Table Person with Prs_ID (PK)
Table Site with Site_ID (PK)
Table Workplace with Plc_ID (PK)
Table Person_Site with Prs_Site_PrsID (PK, FK), Prs_Site_SiteID (PK, FK), Prs_Site_PlcID (FK)
Unique Index on Prs_Site_PlcID
```

I think this should solve the problem. 
Now how can I express this in an ERM?

**Edit:**

I thought it would solve the problem but it doesn't. With this I can't assign one workplace to two different persons, because there is a unique index on the Prs_Site_PlcID column. Back to the beginning...

Comment: Please post your best guess so we can comment on it and suggest improvements.  This is not `do_my_work_for_me.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Note unique index `Ak1` (alternate key) `(SiteID, WorkplaceID)` on `Workplace` which is propagated to `PersonWorkplace`.

```
--
-- PostgreSQL
--
create table Site      (SiteId      integer not null);
create table Person    (PersonId    integer not null);
create table Workplace (WorkplaceID integer not null, SiteID integer not null);
create table PersonWorkplace
(PersonID integer not null, SiteID integer not null, WorkplaceID integer not null);

alter table Site   add constraint pk_Sit primary key (SiteID);
alter table Person add constraint pk_Prs primary key (PersonID);

alter table Workplace
  add constraint  pk_Wpl primary key (WorkplaceID)
, add constraint fk1_Wpl foreign key (SiteId) references Site (SiteId)
, add constraint ak1_Wpl unique (SiteID, WorkplaceID);

alter table PersonWorkplace
  add constraint  pk_PrsWpl primary key (PersonId, SiteID)
, add constraint fk1_PrsWpl foreign key (PersonId) references Person (PersonID)
, add constraint fk2_PrsWpl foreign key (SiteID, WorkplaceID) references Workplace (SiteID, WorkplaceID);
```

Comment: I really like this solution and I can't see a flaw so far. I'll try it on Monday and come back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @Auril, you can also save one index if you pull SiteID into PK of the Workplace table and use `SiteWorkplaceNo` (int, 1,2,3 ...; for each site) instead of `WorkplaceID`

Answer (score 1):

I think the clue is in the question.

You say that each work place has one site - the relationships thus are:

**many persons have many workplaces**

**One workplace has one Site;**

Implementation suggestion:

```
Person table
-----------
person_id primary key
.....

Workplace table
--------------
workplace_id primary_key
site_id (unique index)

person_workplace table
-------------------
person_id
workplace_id

site table
--------------
site_id primary key
```

The unique index on the site_id column in the workplace table ensures that each workplace is associated with a different site.

Comment: This design would make it possible to assign 2 workplaces to one person and both workplaces are at the same site.

Comment: In that case, you can create a unique index on the foreign key column on workplace.

Comment: The unique index would prevent 2 persons sharing the same workplace. But this is possible in my scenario.

Comment: With the unique index on site_id in the workplace table you can only have exactly one workplace at a site. But a site can have n workplaces!

Comment: Well, yeah - that's what your question states...if there's a different relationship between sites and workplaces, you can model that too. Is it 1-1?

Comment: Well one person can only have one workplace per site, but a site has multiple workplaces.

Comment: Ah - ok. What's the business term for a person's assignment to a workplace and site? Is it assignment?

Comment: I would say it is assignment, I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: In that case, Damir Sudarevic's answer looks right - but I'd call the table he names "PersonWorkplace" something more reflective of the business domain - like "Assignment". It's likely that table will have other columns, like start and end date, status etc. You can add a compound unique index to the "person_id", "site_id" and "workplace_id" columns to reflect the rule a person can only be assigned to a single combination of workplace and site.

Answer (score 0):

YOu need an intermediate table EMPLOYEES which represents a PERSON's stint at a worksite working for an employer. A single person can be many employees, i.e. work for more than one employer. Day job / night job, or jobs in succession. EMPLOYEE is not a synonym for the person entity but is a representation of person-at-employer.

Comment: All persons have the same employer, just that they can be at different sites.